# Is there any graphite web ui which dosn't require graphite-webapp?

Tags: python, graphite

I want to deploy statistics visualization solution.
At first glance I'm playing with Graphite.

I would like to have something more interactive then standard django graphite-webapp.
I was looking at some dashboard alternatives http://dashboarddude.com/blog/2013/01/23/dashboards-for-graphite/

But it seams that all of them are a clients for Django graphite-webapp.

Is there any graphite web ui which dosn't require graphite-webapp?

Comment: None at the moment, I think. You can always the the standard webapp as a source of graphs, and use whichever dashboard alternative you want to actually display, collect and manipulate your graphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no alternate dashboards for graphite that don't require the django webapp because its the django webapp that serves up the API for the /render url that every dashboard requires to retrieve data from graphite.

There's currently an experimental Go-based Graphite API server, [graphite-ng](https://github.com/Dieterbe/graphite-ng), but it isn't feature complete.

Comment: *graphite-ng* looks interesting. It doesn't replace *carbon/whisper*?

Comment: No, its purely intended as a replacement/alternative to the Graphite webapp.